# Is Apache SOLR fully certified on vmware?

Tags: solr, benchmarking, vmware

Is Apache SOLR fully certified on vmware ? If yes than are there any benchmarking figures available ?

I have gone through below link, but any other insights would be appreciated.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201303.mbox/%3C008a01ce297c$d0934900$71b9db00$@arcadelia.com%3E

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any benchmarking figures to share - but we have deployed Solr in numerous environments on virtual infrastructure - and we never seen any issues related to virtualization in Solr